Why does LaTeX keeps a blank page after "\end{thebibliography}" and "\input{Anhang}?
I tried \clearpage, \breakpage, \let\relax\clearpage.. nothing works. I'd appreciate every help!
%==========Grundeinstellungen==========%
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper,oneside,listof=totoc,plainfootsepline]{scrbook}
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}

\input{Voreinstellungen.tex}
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{} % This disables \cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}       % This disables \clearpage

%==========Dokument==========%
\begin{document}
\input{Deckblatt}
% Start arabic numbering from Sperrvermerk
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent\hfill\textbf{Seite}\par}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\input{Sperrvermerk}
\input{Danksagung}
\begingroup
\input{Kap1}
\input{Kap2}
\endgroup

\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhaltsverzeichnis}

% Temporarily hide the table of contents from being listed
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\tableofcontents
% Reset tocdepth so further sections are added to the TOC
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\input{Kapitel/Abkuerzungsverzeichnis}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{} 
\input{Vorwort}
\newpage
\input{K2}
\newpage
\input{K3}
\newpage
\input{K4}
\endgroup

\newpage    
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{12}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{1}
\textit{...}
\bibitem{2}
\textit{...}    
\end{thebibliography}
\input{Anhang}
\end{document}


The content of the "Anhang":
\chapter*{Anhang}\label{Anhang}
\subsubsection*{Anhang 1: Rissuntersuchung an Antriebsrädern mit MATLAB}\label{Anhang 1: Rissuntersuchung an Antriebsrädern mit MATLAB}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{SAimages/PapDes}
        \caption[Rissuntersuchung an Antriebsrädern mit MATLAB]{ Rissuntersuchung an Antriebsrädern mit MATLAB}
    \label{Programmablaufplan_Rissdetektion.png}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection*{Anhang 2: Frequenzeinstellungen der Sensorsignale am Datenrecorder}
\label{Einstellungen der Frequenzspektren}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{teil2/Spektralanalyse_Einstellung.JPG}
    \caption[Einstellungen der Frequenzspektren der Sensorsignale]{Einstellungen der Frequenzspektren der Sensorsignale}
    \label{fig:Spektralanalyse_Einstellung2.jpg}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\subsubsection*{Anhang 3: Laufraduntersuchung mittels Spektralanalyse in MATLAB}
\label{Programmablaufplan: Laufraduntersuchung mittels Spektralanalyse in MATLAB}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{teil2/Auswertung_mittel_FFT-Spektralanalyse.png}
    \caption[Laufraduntersuchung mittels Spektralanalyse in MATLAB]{Laufraduntersuchung mittels Spektralanalyse in MATLAB}
    \label{fig:Laufrad-Analyse}
\end{figure}


Unless you've told it otherwise, \chapter always starts on a righthand (odd page). So if the biliography ended on a righthand (odd page) a blank page needs to be inserted before the chapter can start on a righthand page.

Thank you. I guess I should just leave it as it is.

Off-topic: Nothing fruiful is achieved by assigning \labels to unnumbered chapters, sections, subsections, and subsubsections.

@Mico such labels can be used for \pageref and for links.

@UlrikeFischer - Good point -- I hadn't thought of the use in \pageref. I stand corrected. :-)

\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{} % This disables \cleardoublepage \renewcommand{\clearpage}{}       % This disables \clearpage completely breaks latex, anything that happens after that is accidental untested behaviour.

@Mico well I need labeling because I referenced the labeled chapters, sections, subsections that's why I needed to do that :)

@FaMi - Unfortunately, the LaTeX \label-\ref mechanism works only on numbered objects -- including objects such as chapters, sections, etc.
